# EXCEL: Sorting data in excel if criteria is met

Tags: excel, sorting

I have a lot of of entries in the excel. 
Each row is consisted with name, surname, address and random numbers in another column. 
Now, there are some of the duplicates where the Name, Surname and address are carrying different numbers and they are sorted in a rows. 
Is there any function that is going to allow me to copy those numbers from one row and put it into another column that is linked with the name and surname, so I can avoid multiple row entries?
To illustrate a bit, let's say like this:

```html
<table>
<tr><td>Name</td><td>Surname</td><td>Address</td><td>Number</td></tr>
<tr><td>John</td><td>Doe</td><td>NN</td><td>1165454</td></tr>
<tr><td>John</td><td>Doe</td><td>NN</td><td>8789798</td></tr>
<tr><td>John</td><td>Doe</td><td>NN</td><td>4564566</td></tr>
</table>
```

Now I want to have data like this:

```html
<table>
<tr><td>Name</td><td>Surname</td><td>Address</td><td>Number1</td><td>Number2</td><td>Number3</td></tr>
<tr><td>John</td><td>Doe</td><td>NN</td><td>1165454</td><td>8789798</td><td>4564566<td></td></tr>

</table>
```

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with pivot table but you'll need to add new column to be used as `columns` in that pivot table.

That column, given that your data starts from `A1`, should have this formula:

```
="Number"&COUNTIFS($A$2:A2,A2,$B$2:B2,B2,$C$2:C2,C2)
```

Comment: I've been trying to do it in pivot tables, but the thing is that I can't find a way to place my actual numbers as texts under the columns that I made using the formula you provided. When I put the data into the "values" of pivot table, I can not get the actual output in plain text of those numbers under the "NumberX" column. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Add new column to columns and Number column to values. Then remove totals and show data as table.